# Empty nginx logs

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get nginx to log access and error logs. My logs currently have very old content, a mix of logs and gzipped logs.

```
$ ls -la access*.log*
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup       0 Jan  8  2016 access.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup 2261400 Jan  7  2016 access.log.1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup  311947 Dec 30  2015 access.log.10.gz
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup  434744 Dec 29  2015 access.log.11.gz
```

My configuration is:

```
user www-data www-data;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
...
http {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
...
```

Strangely, despite the `user` declaration the worker processes still run as nobody:

```
# ps -eo "%U %G %a" | grep nginx
root     root     nginx: master process /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
nobody   nogroup  nginx: worker process                                                              
nobody   nogroup  nginx: worker process
```

I tried setting the owner of the existing `access.log` and `error.log` files to be `nobody:nogroup` but still it doesn't log anything.

There's nothing (relevant) in `syslog`.

I have tried a mixture (!) or reloading and restarting nginx after changing the configuration file. Still nothing...

How is my configuration incorrect?

Comment: In the first command block, are you actually in the directory named `/var/log/nginx/`? Also, it's possible that  `error_log ` & `access_log` are configured a second time in another file, and the first configuration is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to these topics for configuring nginx user:

[How do I change the NGINX user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/433265/how-do-i-change-the-nginx-user)

[why do nginx process run with user nobody](https://serverfault.com/questions/534497/why-do-nginx-process-run-with-user-nobody)

About nginx empty logs I suggest you to empty logs directory or temporary disable Selinux to see if it's causing the trouble `setenrofce 0`

You can also check if you have the right syntax and [error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) directive is in the correct place.

Comment: Yes, I had reviewed those questions already. As above, I have set the user but it doesn't appear to take effect. I considered a separate "why does the user directive work for me" question but what I actually want to know right now is why the logs don't populate - even with `chmod 777` they still don't work, so I don't think it's permissions.

SELinux is not enabled on this system.

`nginx -t` reports the configuration is ok.

Comment: I also tried clearing out the logs but no difference so far...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and in the end, I went to my root folder and found out there was another `access.log` file, in a different location and this other one was being written to.

```
cd /
find . -name 'access.log'
```